Date function not returning expected Month
I have the below SQL in Oracle DB that I am expecting would return March 1st, 2024 (01-MAR-24) however it is instead returning 01-AUG-24
SELECT TRUNC(TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'MM') - 6, 'MM')
FROM dual

Can anyone tell me why this is behaving this way? I want to select the first day of the month 'X' number of months ago and format as above but this is not behaving as I expect.

Maybe SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -6), 'MM') . See example

You are truncating the date to the start of the month then subtracting 6 days (not 6 months) and finally, truncating the value (which is now in the previous month) to the start of that month.
What you want is
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -6) AS dt FROM DUAL;

or:
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM') - INTERVAL '6' MONTH AS dt FROM DUAL;

Which both output:



DT




2024-03-01 00:00:00



fiddle

I would recommend to avoid the INTERVAL syntax whenever possible and rather use ADD_MONTHS. The INTERVAL syntax often produces exceptions and is unable to find the correct date while ADD_MONTHS works fine. See this sample fiddle

@JonasMetzler The INTERVAL syntax will always work if you are subtracting from the 1st of the month. It only produces errors when you use it on a date at the end of the month and the month your are aiming for does not have sufficient days in the month (so don't use TRUNC(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '6' MONTH, 'MM') - truncate first and then subtract like I show in the answer - which will always work without errors)

@MT0 True, I just don't see a reason to use a function that produces errors in some cases when another function always works correctly.
